# Extract Classes and Relationships from a UML Model stored in XML format

Tags: python-3.x, xml, uml

i am currently working with different UML/SysML Models which I exported into xml files. I have different objects and relationships in the document and i want to cluster them with python. Which is the best way to cluster them? I need to split them so, that i can load them into a Neo4J Graphdatabase and create relationships etc...

Code:

```
    <xmi:XMI xmlns:uml="http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/20131001"
         xmlns:MD_Customization_for_SysML__additional_stereotypes="http://www.magicdraw.com/spec/Customization/180/SysML"
         xmlns:MD_Customization_for_Requirements__additional_stereotypes="http://www.magicdraw.com/spec/Customization/180/Requirements"
         xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/spec/XMI/20131001"
         xmlns:Syndeia_Profile="http://www.magicdraw.com/schemas/Syndeia_Profile.xmi"
         xmlns:sysml="http://www.omg.org/spec/SysML/20150709/SysML"
         xmlns:StandardProfile="http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/20131001/StandardProfile">
   <xmi:documentation xmi:type="xmi:Documentation">
      <xmi:exporter>MagicDraw Clean XMI Exporter</xmi:exporter>
      <xmi:exporterVersion>19.0 v9</xmi:exporterVersion>
   </xmi:documentation>
   <uml:Model xmi:type="uml:Model" xmi:id="eee_1045467100313_135436_1" name="Model">
      <ownedComment xmi:type="uml:Comment" xmi:id="_12_1_8740266_1173856349343_83760_98"
                    body="Author:No Magic, Inc..&#xA;Created:3/11/12 3:54 PM.&#xA;Title:Water Supply sample of SysML 1.3.&#xA;Comment:.&#xA;">
         <annotatedElement xmi:idref="eee_1045467100313_135436_1"/>
      </ownedComment>
      <packagedElement xmi:type="uml:Package" xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331479812761_151548_11623"
                       name="Water Supply">
         <packagedElement xmi:type="uml:Class" xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331479843801_569989_11649"
                          name="Water Supply">
            <ownedAttribute xmi:type="uml:Port" xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331484591214_181062_11815"
                            name="sbank"
                            visibility="public"
                            aggregation="composite"
                            type="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331479862547_919802_11715"
                            association="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331484591214_617783_11814"/>
         </packagedElement>
         <packagedElement xmi:type="uml:Class" xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331479853224_712043_11682"
                          name="Water Client">
            <ownedAttribute xmi:type="uml:Port" xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331484598810_552927_11845"
                            name="faucet"
                            visibility="public"
                            aggregation="composite"
                            type="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331479879251_133971_11781"
                            association="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331484598809_289090_11844"/>
         </packagedElement>
         <packagedElement xmi:type="uml:Class" xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331479862547_919802_11715"
                          name="Spigot Bank">
            <ownedAttribute xmi:type="uml:Port" xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331479925237_470057_11848"
                            name="cold"
                            visibility="public"
                            aggregation="composite"
                            type="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331479871034_682510_11748"
                            association="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331479925236_20827_11847"/>
            <ownedAttribute xmi:type="uml:Property" xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331480379430_664819_11874"
                            name="deliveredTo"
                            visibility="private"
                            type="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331479879251_133971_11781"
                            association="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331480379430_858084_11873">
               <upperValue xmi:type="uml:LiteralUnlimitedNatural"
                           xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331480379432_140833_11877"
                           value="*"/>
            </ownedAttribute>
            <ownedAttribute xmi:type="uml:Port" xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331482799762_714366_11245"
                            name="hot"
                            visibility="public"
                            aggregation="composite"
                            type="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331479871034_682510_11748"
                            association="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331482799762_719985_11244"/>
         </packagedElement>
         <packagedElement xmi:type="uml:Class" xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331479871034_682510_11748"
                          name="Spigot">
            <ownedAttribute xmi:type="uml:Property" xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331484675907_844743_11899"
                            name="to"
                            visibility="private"
                            type="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331479887273_166218_11814"
                            association="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331489981789_245264_13223"/>
         </packagedElement>
         <packagedElement xmi:type="uml:Class" xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331479879251_133971_11781"
                          name="Faucet">
            <ownedAttribute xmi:type="uml:Property" xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331480379430_721368_11875"
                            name="suppliedBy"
                            visibility="private"
                            type="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331479862547_919802_11715"
                            association="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331480379430_858084_11873"/>
            <ownedAttribute xmi:type="uml:Port" xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331482457565_995011_11180"
                            name="cold"
                            visibility="public"
                            aggregation="composite"
                            type="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331479887273_166218_11814"
                            association="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331482457564_87810_11179"/>
            <ownedAttribute xmi:type="uml:Port" xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331483007588_704576_11318"
                            name="hot"
                            visibility="public"
                            aggregation="composite"
                            type="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331479887273_166218_11814"
                            association="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331483007588_935318_11317"/>
         </packagedElement>
         <packagedElement xmi:type="uml:Class" xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331479887273_166218_11814"
                          name="Faucet Inlet">
            <ownedAttribute xmi:type="uml:Property" xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331484675907_42347_11900"
                            name="from"
                            visibility="private"
                            type="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331479871034_682510_11748"
                            association="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331489981789_245264_13223"/>
         </packagedElement>
         <packagedElement xmi:type="uml:Association" xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331479925236_20827_11847">
            <memberEnd xmi:idref="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331479925237_470057_11848"/>
            <memberEnd xmi:idref="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331479925237_146867_11849"/>
            <ownedEnd xmi:type="uml:Property" xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331479925237_146867_11849"
                      visibility="private"
                      type="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331479862547_919802_11715"
                      association="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331479925236_20827_11847"/>
         </packagedElement>
         <packagedElement xmi:type="uml:AssociationClass"
                          xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331480379430_858084_11873"
                          name="Water Delivery">
            <memberEnd xmi:idref="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331480379430_664819_11874"/>
            <memberEnd xmi:idref="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331480379430_721368_11875"/>
            <ownedAttribute xmi:type="uml:Property" xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331483558228_41560_11392"
                            name="suppliedByInLink"
                            visibility="public"
                            type="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331479862547_919802_11715"/>
            <ownedAttribute xmi:type="uml:Property" xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331484184029_995816_11287"
                            name="deliveredToInLink"
                            visibility="public"
                            type="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331479879251_133971_11781"/>
            <ownedConnector xmi:type="uml:Connector" xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331484786667_880942_12016"
                            visibility="public"
                            type="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331489981789_245264_13223">
               <end xmi:type="uml:ConnectorEnd" xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331484786668_54478_12017"
                    partWithPort="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331484184029_995816_11287"
                    role="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331483007588_704576_11318"/>
               <end xmi:type="uml:ConnectorEnd" xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331484786668_349716_12018"
                    partWithPort="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331483558228_41560_11392"
                    role="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331482799762_714366_11245"/>
            </ownedConnector>
            <ownedConnector xmi:type="uml:Connector" xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331484881857_44905_12226"
                            visibility="public"
                            type="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331489981789_245264_13223">
               <end xmi:type="uml:ConnectorEnd" xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331484881857_184544_12227"
                    partWithPort="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331484184029_995816_11287"
                    role="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331482457565_995011_11180"/>
               <end xmi:type="uml:ConnectorEnd" xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331484881857_729524_12228"
                    partWithPort="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331483558228_41560_11392"
                    role="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331479925237_470057_11848"/>
            </ownedConnector>
         </packagedElement>
         <packagedElement xmi:type="uml:Association" xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331482457564_87810_11179">
            <memberEnd xmi:idref="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331482457565_995011_11180"/>
            <memberEnd xmi:idref="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331482457565_116662_11181"/>
            <ownedEnd xmi:type="uml:Property" xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331482457565_116662_11181"
                      visibility="private"
                      type="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331479879251_133971_11781"
                      association="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331482457564_87810_11179"/>
         </packagedElement>
         <packagedElement xmi:type="uml:Association" xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331482799762_719985_11244">
            <memberEnd xmi:idref="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331482799762_714366_11245"/>
            <memberEnd xmi:idref="_19_0_8db0281_1517815224167_423100_13416"/>
            <ownedEnd xmi:type="uml:Port" xmi:id="_19_0_8db0281_1517815224167_423100_13416"
                      visibility="public"
                      aggregation="composite"
                      type="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331479862547_919802_11715"
                      association="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331482799762_719985_11244"/>
         </packagedElement>
         <packagedElement xmi:type="uml:Association" xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331483007588_935318_11317">
            <memberEnd xmi:idref="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331483007588_704576_11318"/>
            <memberEnd xmi:idref="_19_0_8db0281_1517815267437_225388_13505"/>
            <ownedEnd xmi:type="uml:Port" xmi:id="_19_0_8db0281_1517815267437_225388_13505"
                      visibility="public"
                      aggregation="composite"
                      type="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331479879251_133971_11781"
                      association="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331483007588_935318_11317"/>
         </packagedElement>
         <packagedElement xmi:type="uml:Association" xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331484591214_617783_11814">
            <memberEnd xmi:idref="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331484591214_181062_11815"/>
            <memberEnd xmi:idref="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331484591215_151609_11816"/>
            <ownedEnd xmi:type="uml:Property" xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331484591215_151609_11816"
                      visibility="private"
                      type="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331479843801_569989_11649"
                      association="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331484591214_617783_11814"/>
         </packagedElement>
         <packagedElement xmi:type="uml:Association" xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331484598809_289090_11844">
            <memberEnd xmi:idref="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331484598810_552927_11845"/>
            <memberEnd xmi:idref="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331484598810_504945_11846"/>
            <ownedEnd xmi:type="uml:Property" xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331484598810_504945_11846"
                      visibility="private"
                      type="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331479853224_712043_11682"
                      association="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331484598809_289090_11844"/>
         </packagedElement>
         <packagedElement xmi:type="uml:AssociationClass"
                          xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331489981789_245264_13223"
                          name="Plumbing">
            <memberEnd xmi:idref="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331484675907_844743_11899"/>
            <memberEnd xmi:idref="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331484675907_42347_11900"/>
            <ownedAttribute xmi:type="uml:Property" xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331494244567_68138_14488"
                            name="fromInLink"
                            visibility="public"
                            type="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331479871034_682510_11748"/>
            <ownedAttribute xmi:type="uml:Property" xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331494276271_506782_14535"
                            name="toInLink"
                            visibility="public"
                            type="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331479887273_166218_11814"/>
            <ownedAttribute xmi:type="uml:Property" xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331494549107_816307_14733"
                            name="sf"
                            visibility="private"
                            aggregation="composite"
                            type="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331494478778_89914_14621"/>
            <ownedAttribute xmi:type="uml:Property" xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331494552281_76711_14759"
                            name="ff"
                            visibility="private"
                            aggregation="composite"
                            type="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331494478778_89914_14621"/>
            <ownedAttribute xmi:type="uml:Property" xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331494556862_550061_14787"
                            name="pp"
                            visibility="private"
                            aggregation="composite"
                            type="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331494484054_177360_14663"/>
            <ownedConnector xmi:type="uml:Connector" xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331494564407_822564_14837"
                            visibility="public">
               <end xmi:type="uml:ConnectorEnd" xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331494564407_722669_14838"
                    role="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331494244567_68138_14488"/>
               <end xmi:type="uml:ConnectorEnd" xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331494564407_525692_14839"
                    role="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331494549107_816307_14733"/>
            </ownedConnector>
            <ownedConnector xmi:type="uml:Connector" xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331494567377_705937_14862"
                            visibility="public">
               <end xmi:type="uml:ConnectorEnd" xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331494567377_942014_14863"
                    role="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331494549107_816307_14733"/>
               <end xmi:type="uml:ConnectorEnd" xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331494567381_536785_14864"
                    role="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331494556862_550061_14787"/>
            </ownedConnector>
            <ownedConnector xmi:type="uml:Connector" xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331494570302_877043_14886"
                            visibility="public">
               <end xmi:type="uml:ConnectorEnd" xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331494570303_204656_14887"
                    role="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331494556862_550061_14787"/>
               <end xmi:type="uml:ConnectorEnd" xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331494570303_788366_14888"
                    role="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331494552281_76711_14759"/>
            </ownedConnector>
            <ownedConnector xmi:type="uml:Connector" xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331494573394_953166_14910"
                            visibility="public">
               <end xmi:type="uml:ConnectorEnd" xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331494573395_902533_14911"
                    role="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331494552281_76711_14759"/>
               <end xmi:type="uml:ConnectorEnd" xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331494573395_95731_14912"
                    role="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331494276271_506782_14535"/>
            </ownedConnector>
         </packagedElement>
         <packagedElement xmi:type="uml:Class" xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331490926495_30599_11277"
                          name="Bath">
            <generalization xmi:type="uml:Generalization"
                            xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331490926554_970806_11280"
                            general="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331479853224_712043_11682"/>
         </packagedElement>
         <packagedElement xmi:type="uml:Class" xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331490934484_414154_11296"
                          name="Sink">
            <generalization xmi:type="uml:Generalization"
                            xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331490934552_537633_11299"
                            general="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331479853224_712043_11682"/>
         </packagedElement>
         <packagedElement xmi:type="uml:Class" xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331490941572_58127_11316"
                          name="Shower">
            <generalization xmi:type="uml:Generalization"
                            xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331490941639_572075_11319"
                            general="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331479853224_712043_11682"/>
         </packagedElement>
         <packagedElement xmi:type="uml:Class" xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331490977054_352736_11403"
                          name="House 2">
            <ownedAttribute xmi:type="uml:Property" xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331490987076_492068_11499"
                            visibility="private"
                            aggregation="composite"
                            type="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331479843801_569989_11649"/>
            <ownedAttribute xmi:type="uml:Property" xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331490996883_5015_11549"
                            visibility="private"
                            aggregation="composite"
                            type="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331490926495_30599_11277"/>
            <ownedAttribute xmi:type="uml:Property" xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331490999720_919695_11591"
                            visibility="private"
                            aggregation="composite"
                            type="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331490934484_414154_11296"/>
            <ownedAttribute xmi:type="uml:Property" xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331491004321_497701_11635"
                            visibility="private"
                            aggregation="composite"
                            type="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331490941572_58127_11316"/>
            <ownedConnector xmi:type="uml:Connector" xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331491252870_808147_12224"
                            visibility="public"
                            type="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331480379430_858084_11873">
               <end xmi:type="uml:ConnectorEnd" xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331491252870_302956_12225"
                    partWithPort="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331490996883_5015_11549"
                    role="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331484598810_552927_11845"/>
               <end xmi:type="uml:ConnectorEnd" xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331491252871_848839_12226"
                    partWithPort="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331490987076_492068_11499"
                    role="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331484591214_181062_11815"/>
            </ownedConnector>
            <ownedConnector xmi:type="uml:Connector" xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331491255919_566254_12275"
                            visibility="public"
                            type="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331480379430_858084_11873">
               <end xmi:type="uml:ConnectorEnd" xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331491255919_59410_12276"
                    partWithPort="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331490999720_919695_11591"
                    role="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331484598810_552927_11845"/>
               <end xmi:type="uml:ConnectorEnd" xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331491255920_462491_12277"
                    partWithPort="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331490987076_492068_11499"
                    role="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331484591214_181062_11815"/>
            </ownedConnector>
            <ownedConnector xmi:type="uml:Connector" xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331491259903_64972_12326"
                            visibility="public"
                            type="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331480379430_858084_11873">
               <end xmi:type="uml:ConnectorEnd" xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331491259903_929047_12327"
                    partWithPort="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331491004321_497701_11635"
                    role="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331484598810_552927_11845"/>
               <end xmi:type="uml:ConnectorEnd" xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331491259904_856999_12328"
                    partWithPort="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331490987076_492068_11499"
                    role="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331484591214_181062_11815"/>
            </ownedConnector>
         </packagedElement>
         <packagedElement xmi:type="uml:Class" xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331491812810_405298_13180"
                          name="House">
            <ownedAttribute xmi:type="uml:Property" xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331491841483_901900_13276"
                            visibility="private"
                            aggregation="composite"
                            type="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331479843801_569989_11649"/>
            <ownedAttribute xmi:type="uml:Property" xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331491845693_436520_13320"
                            visibility="private"
                            aggregation="composite"
                            type="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331479853224_712043_11682"/>
            <ownedConnector xmi:type="uml:Connector" xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331491890913_206406_13432"
                            visibility="public"
                            type="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331480379430_858084_11873">
               <end xmi:type="uml:ConnectorEnd" xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331491890914_884819_13433"
                    partWithPort="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331491845693_436520_13320"
                    role="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331484598810_552927_11845"/>
               <end xmi:type="uml:ConnectorEnd" xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331491890914_754931_13434"
                    partWithPort="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331491841483_901900_13276"
                    role="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331484591214_181062_11815"/>
            </ownedConnector>
            <ownedConnector xmi:type="uml:Connector" xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331492440897_915570_14035"
                            visibility="public"
                            type="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331489981789_245264_13223">
               <end xmi:type="uml:ConnectorEnd" xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331492440898_16524_14036"`enter code here`
                    partWithPort="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331484598810_552927_11845"
                    role="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331483007588_704576_11318"/>
               <end xmi:type="uml:ConnectorEnd" xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331492440898_221417_14037"
                    partWithPort="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331484591214_181062_11815"
                    role="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331482799762_714366_11245"/>
            </ownedConnector>
            <ownedConnector xmi:type="uml:Connector" xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331492445388_364512_14088"
                            visibility="public"
                            type="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331489981789_245264_13223">
               <end xmi:type="uml:ConnectorEnd" xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331492445388_864777_14089"
                    partWithPort="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331484598810_552927_11845"
                    role="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331482457565_995011_11180"/>
               <end xmi:type="uml:ConnectorEnd" xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331492445389_547113_14090"
                    partWithPort="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331484591214_181062_11815"
                    role="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331479925237_470057_11848"/>
            </ownedConnector>
         </packagedElement>
         <packagedElement xmi:type="uml:Class" xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331494478778_89914_14621"
                          name="Fitting"/>
         <packagedElement xmi:type="uml:Class" xmi:id="_17_0_4_b0002e1_1331494484054_177360_14663"
                          name="Pipe"/>
      </packagedElement>
   </uml:Model>
```

Is it possible to use the ElementTree function to work with these files?

Comment: This is plain XML code and you can parse it with any DOM parser. The XMI format itself is not document anywhere (I found). So you're on yourself with trial and error. I needed some simple XMI and got that working. But it starts getting difficult rather soon you dig into a little more depth.

Comment: Last specification of XMI : https://www.omg.org/spec/XMI/ISO/19509/PDF

Comment: @qwerty_so to search for UML specification : https://www.omg.org/spec/#specs-search-form and then searching for XMI in that page you can found XML Metadata Interchange (XMI®) 2.4.2  19509:2014 formal/14-04-06 giving the links https://www.omg.org/spec/XMI/2.4.2/ and the spec itself https://www.omg.org/spec/XMI/2.4.2/PDF

Comment: @bruno I did search for it. But some time ago. Maybe 2 years? That time there was nothing but a blurb document - not usable. Though it reads 2014 I'm pretty sure I looked later. Their publishing cycle does not match, I guess. Anyway, thanks for the pointer. (I doubt I'll dig too deep into that since each vendor just uses his own additional undocumented flavor.)